# Principal ultrafilters and a bijection

Tags: logic, set-theory, lambda-calculus

In "Compositionality in Montague Grammar" (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0b5d/ab9d1718d6ca0c7211c0d81c9a65e4a03759.pdf), talking about classical higher-order logic, Markus Kracht writes that

> Montague assumed that.../John/ no longer denotes the individual John but rather the set of properties true of John. In a standard model (where we allow quantifying over all subsets) there is a biunique correspondence between the individuals of the domain and the set of all subsets of the domain containing that individual (such sets are also called principal ultrafilters) (p.12).

He seems to be talking about a standard model of the simply typed lambda calculus, in which quantifiers can range over entities of any type and function types $\alpha \to \beta$ (for types $\alpha, \beta$) are not restricted to a proper subset of the functions from expressions of type $\alpha$ to expressions of type $\beta$. In this context, where $e, t$ are the type of entities and boolean truth values (respectively), the relevant bijection would be between entities of type $e$ (individuals) and entities of type $(e \to t) \to t$ (sets of sets of individuals).

But the cardinality of a set of sets is surely larger than the cardinality of a single individual (the member of all the sets in the principal ultrafilter). So how can there be such a bijection?

I can see how in there is an injection sending every individual in a model to the set of sets containing that individual. But how can there be an injection from the set of all sets containing an individual to that individual, if individuals and sets of sets differ in cardinality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can there be an injection from the set of all sets containing an individual to that individual, if individuals and sets of sets differ in cardinality?

There can't, and calling this "biunique" is a bit cluncky in my opinion, but I didn't read the article for further context.

Using your notation, you get an injection from $e$ to $(e \to t) \to t$, and that is all that the author claims. Then there is a "biunique" correspondence between the elements of $e$ and the sets-of-sets that are in the image of this injection. That is, if you have a set-of-sets of which you already know that it is the set of all sets containing some individual $x : e$, then in fact this individual is unique (and it is given by the unique element of the intersection of all the sets in the set). But for a general set-of-sets, no such $x$ will exist; just consider a set containing only two disjoint sets, or a set containing no set at all.

Comment: So there is a bijection between individuals and principal ultrafilters (which are special cases of sets of sets), but not a bijection between individuals and sets of sets? If we know that some set of sets is a principal ultrafilter (but we don't know what individual generates it), we can recover the individual which generates it?

Comment: Yes. That follows from Cantor's theorem, which holds constructively. But even if you are working in a setting with such weak axioms that Cantor's theorem does not hold, the injection I describe in my answer is the correspondence apparently described by the author, and that certainly is never a bijection, even if it were possible to have a bijection.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "can". You can take the intersection of all those sets, and then retrieve the unique element in the set that remains, if those are "operations" available to you.

Comment: Were you saying (it wasn't entirely clear to me) `Yes' to the statement that there IS a bijection between individuals and principal ultrafilters given modest assumptions about the operations available (and denying that there is a bijection between individuals and sets of sets)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying, with some caveats about very unusual situations/definitions.

Comment: One thing that's confusing me is that the type `((a -> b) -> b) -> a` is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509788/the-intuition-behind-the-definition-of-the-co-reader-monad not constructively valid (since if we set $b:= \bot$ we get an instance of double negation elimination). But in a model of the simply typed lambda calculus we can construct define function mapping a principal ultrafilter to an individual. Does this simply mean that, although there is such a function in the model, we cannot define a $lambda\, term$ expressing it?

Comment: There is not term $((e \to t) \to t) \to e$, because it does not work on the full type, just the "image" of the injection $e \to ((e \to t) \to t)$. There especially is not a term of the *general* type $((a \to b) \to b) \to a$ for the reason you point out. If you want to go further with this I recommend you ask a new question, a comment section is not a good medium for ever more detailed questions.